# Was Yuuzhan'tar and Zonama Sekot Force use similar to that of the Jedi or other Force using sects?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

In a couple of instances in the books these sentient planets seem to display Force powers, like when Yuuzhan'tar strips the Vong of the Force or when Zonama Sekot uses the Force to make Force projections to talk to people on the planet.

My understanding is that in these instances, the planets were using the Force in some way. So could they themselves use the Force like throw Force lightning on an entire system like the Sith or move planets out of orbit?

Comment: I fixed a typo in your title and made the first sentence in the question body slightly clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure about zapping a system or knocking planets out of orbit, but Zonama Sekot can shoot itself through hyperspace. Additionally, Sekot (the intelligence) is what’s force sensitive, not the planet Zonama. Additionally, Zonama Sekot is just a seed of Yuuzhan’tar, not a separately evolved planet. Sekot (the intelligence) doesn’t seem to have the sort of nature (based of what I’ve read in the books) to fry a system with lightning (not to mention the ridiculous energy needed) or knock a potentially habitable planet out of orbit. It seems much more intrested in protecting itself and hiding, not about attacking others.  I don’t know much about Yuuzhan’tar though (sorry).

Comment: As I recall (although my copy of *The Final Prophecy* has gone missing) Zonama Sekot had technological devices fitted to it to allow it to jump into hyperspace. It might have navigated by use of the Force, which isn't unknown for Jedi - Kyp Durron could do it to some extent.

Comment: @Cadence, you’re probably right, it’s been a while since I read that specific book.